# Polyline not shown on google staticmap

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am currently working with googles API for static maps to show a route between two points. I am receiving a polyline from google's directions API which I want to be shown on the static map. 
The problem is, that the line won't show in some cases. I have a working example but also non-working ones and it seems I'm unable to find the problem on my own, so please tell me if you can find it.

This one works like a charm:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=670x448&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:ktfeHy`}bBj@b@?JIv@BfA_A~EfApAOz@|C|AjAp@Pq@DEl@Tl@XXVhBv@ZXp@t@hA|@bBvAPNCb@tAl@dEhBcAlHO|@]n@WtCYnAQ|@gApBh@t@vB`EvCdGPZZ^n@f@`AlAbA`BXv@n@nBf@xD|@dGt@jEnAfGbBvIl@a@`@e@&visual_refresh=true&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker_schlafen.gif%7Cshadow:true%7Clabel:%7CBarnabitengasse+14,+1060&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker.gif%7Cshadow:true%7C48.2082647,16.373920599999998
```

[Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=670x448&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:ktfeHy%60%7DbBj%40b%40%3FJIv%40BfA_A~EfApAOz%40%7CC%7CAjAp%40Pq%40DEl%40Tl%40XXVhBv%40ZXp%40t%40hA%7C%40bBvAPNCb%40tAl%40dEhBcAlHO%7C%40%5Dn%40WtCYnAQ%7C%40gApBh%40t%40vB%60EvCdGPZZ%5En%40f%40%60AlAbA%60BXv%40n%40nBf%40xD%7C%40dGt%40jEnAfGbBvIl%40a%40%60%40e%40&visual_refresh=true&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker_schlafen.gif%7Cshadow:true%7Clabel:%7CBarnabitengasse+14,+1060&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker.gif%7Cshadow:true%7C48.2082647,16.373920599999998)

But this one, for example, won't:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=670x532&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:ktfeHy`}bBj@b@?JIv@BfA_A~EfApAHa@xC^~C^lANfC`AhDvAp@VX?xAf@@EBAjBp@xAz@l@Xx@f@vDzAlA`@rF|BjC|@`BrALjAHG^jBLL%E0%AF%BATl@PbAPfCBfBCdBQ~ABz@LvALlBRdADrBTrCd@bB`@bBfADBJ@vAnAfB`BhAt@`Ad@dB|@ZZ~AjAlA`AxEtDfA~@PPJKzEiFbC_CtAsAhEgEVc@z@iBjD|F|AzBA`@hBD~Hj@|Hj@JuDzBRpAJ&visual_refresh=true&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker_schlafen.gif%7Cshadow:true%7Clabel:%7CKarmarschgasse+43,+1100&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker.gif%7Cshadow:true%7C48.2082647,16.373920599999998
```

[Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=670x532&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:ktfeHy%60%7DbBj%40b%40%3FJIv%40BfA_A~EfApAHa%40xC%5E~C%5ElANfC%60AhDvAp%40VX%3FxAf%40%40EBAjBp%40xAz%40l%40Xx%40f%40vDzAlA%60%40rF%7CBjC%7C%40%60BrALjAHG%5EjBLL%E0%AF%BATl%40PbAPfCBfBCdBQ~ABz%40LvALlBRdADrBTrCd%40bB%60%40bBfADBJ%40vAnAfB%60BhAt%40%60Ad%40dB%7C%40ZZ~AjAlA%60AxEtDfA~%40PPJKzEiFbC_CtAsAhEgEVc%40z%40iBjD%7CF%7CAzBA%60%40hBD~Hj%40%7CHj%40JuDzBRpAJ&visual_refresh=true&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker_schlafen.gif%7Cshadow:true%7Clabel:%7CKarmarschgasse+43,+1100&markers=icon:http://kolo-tower.at/images/map_marker.gif%7Cshadow:true%7C48.2082647,16.373920599999998)

Any hint is appreciated.

**SOLVED**

Thanks, guys. Turned out, even the output of googles api need to be urlencoded.

Comment: Your second polyline has a large jump in the path (paste it into the [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) and decode it to see what it looks like), is that correct?  If not, what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: didn't URL encode the enc: path correctly: [wrkg](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=670x532&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:ktfeHy%60%7DbBj%40b%40%3FJIv%40BfA_A~EfApAHa%40xC%5E~C%5ElANfC%60AhDvAp%40VX%3FxAf%40%40EBAjBp%40xAz%40l%40Xx%40f%40vDzAlA%60%40rF%7CBjC%7C%40%60BrALjAHG%5EjBLLzpBl%40PbAPfCBfBCdBQ~ABz%40LvALlBRdADrBTrCd%40bB%60%40bBfADBJ%40vAnAfB%60BhAt%40%60Ad%40dB%7C%40ZZ~AjAlA%60AxEtDfA~%40PPJKzEiFbC_CtAsAhEgEVc%40z%40iBjD%7CF%7CAzBA%60%40hBD~Hj%40%7CHj%40JuDzBRpAJ%40&visual_refresh=true&markers=label:%7CKarmarschgasse+43,+1100&markers=48.2082647,16.373920599999998)

Comment: The interactive polyline encoder shows me the line as it should be.

Comment: @user3100343 (or @geocodezip) Could you submit an answer this question so it isn't listed as unanswered?

Comment: Weird looking line, but posted as an answer.  [The documentation on static maps talks about URL encoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#url-size-restriction).

Comment: @user3100343, I edited the answer into my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you didn't URL encode the line correctly:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=670x532&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:ktfeHy%60%7DbBj%40b%40%3FJIv%40BfA_A~EfApAHa%40xC%5E~C%5ElANfC%60AhDvAp%40VX%3FxAf%40%40EBAjBp%40xAz%40l%40Xx%40f%40vDzAlA%60%40rF%7CBjC%7C%40%60BrALjAHG%5EjBLLzpBl%40PbAPfCBfBCdBQ~ABz%40LvALlBRdADrBTrCd%40bB%60%40bBfADBJ%40vAnAfB%60BhAt%40%60Ad%40dB%7C%40ZZ~AjAlA%60AxEtDfA~%40PPJKzEiFbC_CtAsAhEgEVc%40z%40iBjD%7CF%7CAzBA%60%40hBD~Hj%40%7CHj%40JuDzBRpAJ%40&visual_refresh=true&markers=label:%7CKarmarschgasse+43,+1100&markers=48.2082647,16.373920599999998
```

[link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=670x532&path=weight:3%7Ccolor:blue%7Cenc:ktfeHy%60%7DbBj%40b%40%3FJIv%40BfA_A~EfApAHa%40xC%5E~C%5ElANfC%60AhDvAp%40VX%3FxAf%40%40EBAjBp%40xAz%40l%40Xx%40f%40vDzAlA%60%40rF%7CBjC%7C%40%60BrALjAHG%5EjBLLzpBl%40PbAPfCBfBCdBQ~ABz%40LvALlBRdADrBTrCd%40bB%60%40bBfADBJ%40vAnAfB%60BhAt%40%60Ad%40dB%7C%40ZZ~AjAlA%60AxEtDfA~%40PPJKzEiFbC_CtAsAhEgEVc%40z%40iBjD%7CF%7CAzBA%60%40hBD~Hj%40%7CHj%40JuDzBRpAJ%40&visual_refresh=true&markers=label:%7CKarmarschgasse+43,+1100&markers=48.2082647,16.373920599999998)